# reading cell value from tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am new in objective-c i want ur help
my question is that i have tableview with 10 cell each cell is field with some data that are come from tabase later i change some of the cell value from table view and now i want to read this all cell value from table view after table view reload with new value then how can i do
how can i stored it in new array 
i am trying to do something like this it is correct or not if not then how can i do

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated // after new value will insert 
{

[tableView reloadData];
NSArray *visibleRowsArr = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[visibleRowsArr objectAtIndex:0]];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

in viewwillappear

[tableview reloadData] should be at the end of viewwillappear that is before }

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy, you can try use the same array from which you are reloading the whole table.

Because after all that array would have been updated so there is no need to read the records from TableViewCells but try it using with Array.

like :

```
int AtOurWish =5;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated // after new value will insert 
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

[self.YourArray objectAtIndex:AtOurWish];//Index At which you want to access the array

[tableView reloadData];
NSArray *visibleRowsArr = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[visibleRowsArr objectAtIndex:0]];


}
```

Otherwise you edit you question since it's not much clear!!!